# Make thumbnails for jpeg images in pure Lua?

Tags: resize, lua, exif, image-resizing, shrink

Lua -> Is it possible to Shrink Larger Image ?

I need it to make thumbnails for jpeg images.

I don't need a "binding". Is there any module writed in pure Lua ?
Is it difficult to write one ?

I have found these:

- https://github.com/tnodir/luafreeimage
- http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/im/
- http://ittner.github.com/lua-gd/manual.html#intro

but they all use C libraries.
Also, do you think it is possible to read Exif Data of Photographs in pure LUA ?

Comment: What's the problem with using libraries that bind to C?

Comment: I use LUA with Corona SDK (Corona lets developers use integrated Lua, layered on top of C++/OpenGL), but there is no way to run C code (At the moment, Corona doesn't allow the use of external C modules and libraries). So I have to use just LUA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but no one has done it, because it is difficult and kindof pointless, since Lua interfaces very nicely with C.

Comment: What about reading EXIF data. It is still so difficult ?
I found an exif reader writed in javascript, What about LUA ?

Comment: I don't think someone has done something so specific. But the code is there, translating from javascript to Lua is not particularly difficult (I'm not volunteering, though). Biggest difficulty would be getting Lua to read binary data (Lua 5.2 has some binary features missing in 5.1)